# Do we need transit visas for Iceland if we have a two-hour layover?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, kef, icelandair

We are holding Indian passports. We are planning to book flights from London to Newark (EWR), USA via Reykjavík (KEF), Iceland. We will have layover in Reykjavík for two hours. We have valid USA visas and UK Standard Visitor visas.

Do we need any visa (like a transit visa) to stay in Reykjavík airport during the layover?

Answer (score 3):

According to [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/) no transit visas are required for you as:

> Holders of confirmed onward tickets transiting on the same calendar day.

Comment: Not sure whether i can proceed to book flights based on this...

Comment: @Ashok your airline will refer to the same Timatic data to allow you to board. You can also [refer to Iceland's offical gov't information](http://www.utl.is/index.php/en/who-does-not-need-a-visa) for further reassurance.